# I want to insert some OLI in a test class but i get NULL

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, product

I have the following code

```
    //Creamos una lista con los line items que iremos añadiendo y quitando que referencian a 2 vehiculos y 1 accesorio
    List<OpportunityLineItem> olitest = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    //Productos
    Product2 p1 = [select Id,Name from Product2 where Name = 'AX6-X80CXXX-XXX'];    //vehiculo
    System.debug(p1.Name);
    Product2 p2 = [select Id,Name from Product2 where Name = 'AX6-X85CXXX-XXX'];    //vehiculo
    System.debug(p2.Name);
    Product2 p3 = [select Id,Name from Product2 where Name = 'Calderines de aluminio'];//accesorio
    System.debug(p3.Name);
    //Entradas de precio de libros
    PriceBookEntry pb1 = [select Id,Product2Id,Product2.Id,Product2.Name from PriceBookEntry where Product2Id=:p1.Id];
    PriceBookEntry pb2 = [select Id,Product2Id,Product2.Id,Product2.Name from PriceBookEntry where Product2Id=:p2.Id];
    PriceBookEntry pb3 = [select Id,Product2Id,Product2.Id,Product2.Name from PriceBookEntry where Product2Id=:p3.Id];
    //lista con los OLI
    olitest.add(new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=op1.Id,PricebookEntryId=pb1.Id,Quantity=1));
    olitest.add(new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=op1.Id,PricebookEntryId=pb2.Id,Quantity=1));
    olitest.add(new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=op1.Id,PricebookEntryId=pb3.Id,Quantity=1));

    insert olitest[0]; System.assertEquals('AX6-X80CXXX-XXX\n',op1.Nombre_de_veh_culos__c);
    insert olitest[1]; System.assertEquals('AX6-X80CXXX-XXX\n AX6-X85CXXX-XXX\n',op1.Nombre_de_veh_culos__c);
    delete olitest[1]; System.assertEquals('AX6-X80CXXX-XXX\n',op1.Nombre_de_veh_culos__c);
    insert olitest[3]; System.assertEquals('AX6-X80CXXX-XXX\n',op1.Nombre_de_veh_culos__c);
    delete olitest[0]; delete olitest[3]; System.assert(String.isEmpty(op1.Nombre_de_veh_culos__c));
```

And i cant figure out how to properly insert some OLIs, the first Assert gets:
    Assertion failed: Expected: AX6-X80CXXX-XXX, Actual: null

Comment: Where are you inserting Op1 ie. Opportunity....

Comment: You are asserting the value of the `Nombre_de_veh_culos__c` custom field on `Opportunity` and that field is null. So if the code you are testing is meant to fill that value in, it is that code (that you have not included in your question) that is failing.

Comment: To add to what Keith is saying, when you insert something and triggers run you need to requery the OLI from the database. The local variable will not be changed as a result of you doing the insert statement

Comment: Op1 opportunity is added just before that code @Subhash:
         `Opportunity op1 = new Opportunity(Name='OpTest',AccountId=ac1.Id,LeadSource='Facebook',Contacto__c=co1.Id,Idioma__c='Español', StageName='Toma de requerimientos',Tipo_de_registro__c='Chasis (CH)',CloseDate=date.today());
        insert op1;`
The fact is that I tested manually the trigger related to this test and it does modify  the field Nombre_de_veh_culos__c, so that's why I think the problem is my insertion in the test class @Keith C.
I also added right before the insert a select to update the op1, but still null.

Comment: Give this Nombre_de_veh_culos__c field a value in the test class. Like Nombre_de_veh_culos__c='NameOfVehicle' in the Opportunity op1 itself...

Answer (score 0):

Give like below

```
Opportunity(Name='OpTest', AccountId=ac1.Id,
            LeadSource='Facebook', Contacto__c=co1.‌​Id,
            Idioma__c='Español', StageName='Toma de requerimientos',
            Tipo_de_registro__c='Chasis (CH)',
            CloseDate=date.today(), Nombre_de_veh_culos__c='Benz'
           );
insert op1;
```

Hope this might helps...

Answer (score 0):

It's done, i just needed to update the modified fields as @DougB said, thank you all.

```
insert olitest[0];
op1 = [select Id,Name,Nombre_de_veh_culos__c from Opportunity where Id=:op1.Id];
System.assertEquals('AX6-X80CXXX-XXX',op1.Nombre_de_veh_culos__c);
```